# How do I make a text that writes the selected date in my calendar?

Tags: javascript, html

I just started learning Javascript, so I apologize in advance for my ignorance. I have copy-pasted a calendar into my website, and I'd like to make a text that writes the date that has been selected in the calendar. I don't really know where to begin or if there's a simple solution to this. I hope I'm not being too ambitious :)

Here's the code for the calendar (imported from a js file):

```
    return function(t) {
        function e(t, e, a) {
            t && (t.attachEvent ? t.attachEvent("on" + e, a) : t.addEventListener(e, a))
        }

        function a(t, e, a) {
            t && (t.detachEvent ? t.detachEvent("on" + e, a) : t.removeEventListener(e, a))
        }
        let n = {
            selector: null,
            datesFilter: !1,
            pastDates: !0,
            availableWeekDays: [],
            availableDates: [],
            date: new Date,
            todaysDate: new Date,
            button_prev: null,
            button_next: null,
            month: null,
            month_label: null,
            onSelect: (t, e) => {},
            months: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
            shortWeekday: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
        };
        for (let e in t) n.hasOwnProperty(e) && (n[e] = t[e]);
        let l = document.querySelector(n.selector);
        if (!l) return;
        const d = function(t) {
                let e = document.createElement("div"),
                    a = document.createElement("span");
                a.innerHTML = t.getDate(), e.className = "vanilla-calendar-date", e.setAttribute("data-calendar-date", t);
                let l = n.availableWeekDays.filter(e => e.day === t.getDay() || e.day === function(t) {
                        return ["sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday"][t]
                    }(t.getDay())),
                    d = n.availableDates.filter(e => e.date === t.getFullYear() + "-" + String(t.getMonth() + 1).padStart("2", 0) + "-" + String(t.getDate()).padStart("2", 0));
                1 === t.getDate() && (e.style.marginLeft = 14.28 * t.getDay() + "%"), n.date.getTime() <= n.todaysDate.getTime() - 1 && !n.pastDates ? e.classList.add("vanilla-calendar-date--disabled") : n.datesFilter ? l.length ? (e.classList.add("vanilla-calendar-date--active"), e.setAttribute("data-calendar-data", JSON.stringify(l[0])), e.setAttribute("data-calendar-status", "active")) : d.length ? (e.classList.add("vanilla-calendar-date--active"), e.setAttribute("data-calendar-data", JSON.stringify(d[0])), e.setAttribute("data-calendar-status", "active")) : e.classList.add("vanilla-calendar-date--disabled") : (e.classList.add("vanilla-calendar-date--active"), e.setAttribute("data-calendar-status", "active")), t.toString() === n.todaysDate.toString() && e.classList.add("vanilla-calendar-date--today"), e.appendChild(a), n.month.appendChild(e)
            },
            r = function() {
                l.querySelectorAll("[data-calendar-status=active]").forEach(t => {
                    t.addEventListener("click", function() {
                        document.querySelectorAll(".vanilla-calendar-date--selected").forEach(t => {
                            t.classList.remove("vanilla-calendar-date--selected")
                        });
                        let t = this.dataset,
                            e = {};
                        t.calendarDate && (e.date = t.calendarDate), t.calendarData && (e.data = JSON.parse(t.calendarData)), n.onSelect(e, this), this.classList.add("vanilla-calendar-date--selected")
                    })
                })
            },
            s = function() {
                o();
                let t = n.date.getMonth();
                for (; n.date.getMonth() === t;) d(n.date), n.date.setDate(n.date.getDate() + 1);
                n.date.setDate(1), n.date.setMonth(n.date.getMonth() - 1), n.month_label.innerHTML = n.months[n.date.getMonth()] + " " + n.date.getFullYear(), r()
            },
            i = function() {
                n.date.setMonth(n.date.getMonth() - 1), s()
            },
            c = function() {
                n.date.setMonth(n.date.getMonth() + 1), s()
            },
            o = function() {
                n.month.innerHTML = ""
            };
        this.init = function() {
            document.querySelector(n.selector).innerHTML = '\n            <div class="vanilla-calendar-header">\n                <button type="button" class="vanilla-calendar-btn" data-calendar-toggle="previous"><svg height="24" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M20,11V13H8L13.5,18.5L12.08,19.92L4.16,12L12.08,4.08L13.5,5.5L8,11H20Z"></path></svg></button>\n                <div class="vanilla-calendar-header__label" data-calendar-label="month"></div>\n                <button type="button" class="vanilla-calendar-btn" data-calendar-toggle="next"><svg height="24" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M4,11V13H16L10.5,18.5L11.92,19.92L19.84,12L11.92,4.08L10.5,5.5L16,11H4Z"></path></svg></button>\n            </div>\n            <div class="vanilla-calendar-week"></div>\n            <div class="vanilla-calendar-body" data-calendar-area="month"></div>\n            ', n.button_prev = document.querySelector(n.selector + " [data-calendar-toggle=previous]"), n.button_next = document.querySelector(n.selector + " [data-calendar-toggle=next]"), n.month = document.querySelector(n.selector + " [data-calendar-area=month]"), n.month_label = document.querySelector(n.selector + " [data-calendar-label=month]"), n.date.setDate(1), s(), document.querySelector(`${n.selector} .vanilla-calendar-week`).innerHTML = `\n                <span>${n.shortWeekday[0]}</span>\n                <span>${n.shortWeekday[1]}</span>\n                <span>${n.shortWeekday[2]}</span>\n                <span>${n.shortWeekday[3]}</span>\n                <span>${n.shortWeekday[4]}</span>\n                <span>${n.shortWeekday[5]}</span>\n                <span>${n.shortWeekday[6]}</span>\n            `, e(n.button_prev, "click", i), e(n.button_next, "click", c)
        }, this.destroy = function() {
            a(n.button_prev, "click", i), a(n.button_next, "click", c), o(), document.querySelector(n.selector).innerHTML = ""
        }, this.reset = function() {
            this.destroy(), this.init()
        }, this.set = function(t) {
            for (let e in t) n.hasOwnProperty(e) && (n[e] = t[e]);
            s()
        }, this.init()
    }
}();
window.VanillaCalendar = VanillaCalendar;
```

Here's the jscode from the html file:

```
<script>

    let pastDates = true, availableDates = false, availableWeekDays = false

    let calendar = new VanillaCalendar({
        selector: "#myCalendar",
        months: ["Januar", "Februar", "Marts", "April", "Maj", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"],
        shortWeekday: ['Man', 'Tir', 'Ons', 'Tor', 'Fre', 'Lør', 'Søn'],
        onSelect: (data, elem) => {
            console.log(data, elem)
        }
    })

    let btnPastDates = document.querySelector('[name=pastDates]')
    btnPastDates.addEventListener('click', () => {
        pastDates = !pastDates
        calendar.set({pastDates: pastDates})
        btnPastDates.innerText = `${(pastDates ? 'Disable' : 'Enable')} past dates`
    })

    let btnAvailableDates = document.querySelector('[name=availableDates]')
    btnAvailableDates.addEventListener('click', () => {
        availableDates = !availableDates
        btnAvailableDates.innerText = `${(availableDates ? 'Clear available dates' : 'Set available dates')}`
        if (!availableDates) {
            calendar.set({availableDates: [], datesFilter: false})
            return
        }
        let dates = () => {
            let result = []
            for (let i = 1; i < 15; ++i) {
                if (i % 2) continue
                let date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000) * i)
                result.push({date: `${String(date.getFullYear())}-${String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, 0)}-${String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, 0)}`})
            }
            return result
        }
        calendar.set({availableDates: dates(), availableWeekDays: [], datesFilter: true})
    })

    let btnAvailableWeekDays = document.querySelector('[name=availableWeekDays]')
    btnAvailableWeekDays.addEventListener('click', () => {
        availableWeekDays = !availableWeekDays
        btnAvailableWeekDays.innerText = `${(availableWeekDays ? 'Clear available weekdays' : 'Set available weekdays')}`
        if (!availableWeekDays) {
            calendar.set({availableWeekDays: [], datesFilter: false})
            return
        }
        let days = [{
            day: 'monday'
        }, {
            day: 'tuesday'
        }, {
            day: 'wednesday'
        }, {
            day: 'friday'
        }]
        calendar.set({availableWeekDays: days, availableDates: [], datesFilter: true})
    })


</script>
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean by ```i'd like to make a text that writes the date that has been selected in the calendar``` Where are you wanting to write it?

Comment: Hello @Albert Moestrup, learning by just jumping into some code is a valid approach for tackling a new language. But it only really works if you are familiar with a fair amount of the concepts behind programming and know at least one other language very well. I might be completely wrong with this, but in your case I would suggest a more structured approach. There are lots of very well written, interactive JavaScript tutorials on the web. Why not start with one of those? For example [the one from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/). I am sure you will be able to solve your problem soon.